# Why is the id same for these two objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

In the below code, why is the id of parent and child the same? Should they not be different?

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        print(id(self))

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        print(id(self))
        super().__init__()
Child()
```

Comment: By definition, `self` is a reference to the instance, so it must always be the same.

Comment: The use of `super` obscures the fact that `Child.__init__` is effectively just calling `Parent.__init__(self)`, passing the same object it received as an argument to `Parent.__init__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only created a single object; it has the same ID whether you are viewing it as the `Child` that it is, or the `Parent` that it inherits from.